# Unhandled exception is not being caught by the handlers

Tags: c#, exception

We have registered for the unhandled exceptions in the following way. The application is a remoting server. If an unhandled exception is thrown from the remoting server it is not handled by the unhandled exception handlers. What could be the problem?

```
[STAThread]

[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnThreadException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
    .
    .
    .

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(form);

}
```

Comment: Where is the exception thrown (stacktrace) and is it thrown in the same appdomain?

Comment: Is this problem occuring on a x64 OS ?

Comment: The problem is occuring in 32 bit OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this method helps you '[Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx)'. It instructs the application how to respond to unhandled exceptions.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnThreadException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);

    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(form);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a remoting server and the exception is happening as part of client interaction, then the exception will be sent to the client without causing the server to crash.

Comment: the server application crashed. This means that the exception is thrown not as part of client interaction

Comment: Oh it did crash, wasn't sure.

Comment: If the server is crashing, what should one do?