# Problem with SOAP api failure not being caught by exception handlers - displays "This application is in break mode"

Tags: c#, soap

I am trying to write a C# program that interacts with the Objective Electronic Records Document Management System [EDRMS] [see https://objective.com/] using its webtalk SOAP api.

One of the things I need to do is create a folder.  To do that I am caling the createRequest api

The problem is that [sometimes] when I attempt to create a folder, the folder I want to use as the parent folder is unable to have folders of the type specified.

This problem is expected in the context of the program execution and cannot readily be avoided.

It relates to folders that were created in the UAT environment which was then refreshed from production - meaning some of the folder id's we have recorded in our DEV/UAT system relate to folders that no longer exist in the UAT objective environment.  Thus it is entirely expected that it would fail when an attempt is made to create a sub-folder with a parent folder which cannot accept sub-folders.

Updating our DEV/UAT system to match production isn't an option right now, so I need to just handle these errors by skipping past them when the problem occurs.

What I want to do is catch this exception when it occurs, and handle the situation gracefully.

The problem that I have is, no matter how many try/catch exception handlers I place around the code that calls the web-service, C# fails to catch it and Visual Studio displays a dialog with the message 'This application is in break mode' and throws unhandled exception

I have been looking at this question

[Visual Studio 2017 studio showing error 'This application is in break mode' and throws unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418120/visual-studio-2017-studio-showing-error-this-application-is-in-break-mode-and)

but the settings that it suggests adjusting don't really stop the program seizing up.

This question also didn't help me:

[Unhandled exception is not being caught by the handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329785/unhandled-exception-is-not-being-caught-by-the-handlers)

since the program I'm running is a console application - my console app only uses one thread.

The code in question where the error occurs is:

```
    ...
    createService.Url = URL_BASE + "/services/create";
    // other code to set up the create service [which works just fine for many other calls]
    ...
    createRequest createRequest = new createRequest();
    // code to add the folder details to the create request


    try
    {
        createResult = createService.send(createRequest);  // <--- Problem occurs when we call the send method to call the soap api
    }
    catch (FaultException fe)
    {
        string message =
        "Error when creating folder ";
        Logger.LogException(message, fe);
        throw new Exception(message, fe);
    }
    catch (SoapException se)
    {
        string message =
        "Error when creating folder ";
        Logger.LogException(message, se);
        XmlQualifiedName code = new XmlQualifiedName();
        throw new SoapException(message, code, se);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string message =
        "Error when creating folder ";

        Logger.LogException(message, e);
        throw new Exception(message, e);
    }
```

When the error occurs, none of these catch's catch the error [including the final one which *should* catch *everything* not already caught].

Instead Visual Studio stops and displays a dialog box complaining of an uncaught exception.

Note that the "send" method looks like this:

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("createsessionResult", Namespace="urn:objective.com")]
    public createsessionResult send([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="urn:objective.com")] createsessionRequest createsessionRequest) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("send", new object[] {
                    createsessionRequest});
        return ((createsessionResult)(results[0]));
    }
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  The send is actually calling a SOAP service, and the error occurs in the service being called.  But what I want to do is detect that the call failed and then handle the situation by unravelling back up the call chain to a point in the processing loop where the issue can simply be noted and the process can skip this call and carry on.

Instead, the whole program fails at this point.

Any thoughts on how to get past this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is probably occurring in CreateRequest().  The managed library when an exception occurs in a method will often jump to a different exception handler.  If the exception is already handled inside the CreateRequest() adding additional exception handler will not capture an event that was already captured.  You may be able to slove issue by checking the URL path and see if the folder will allow the files to be created.

Comment: Thanks Jdweng - I know for a fact that the point at which the error occurs, the folder being passed in as a parent is unable to have the new file created in it - but i cannot know ahead of time if this is so, since the only thing i have is an object id that does not allow me to determine its capabilities.  Thus I want to try creating the file, and allow it to fail and capture the resulting exception/error.  However, when the error occurs it bypasses my exception handling... the CreateRequest is simply a datastructure which gets converted to XML to go over the wire to the SOAP api

Comment: What value is createResult when you cannot create the file?

Comment: When the file cannot be created, createResult never receives a value - as soon as the createService.send(createRequest); method is callled, an exception occurs which is caught [only] by my visual studio IDE [and not by the try/catch that I have surrounded this call with].

Comment: Is the issue the file cannot be created or the xml format is bad?If it is a file write issues the only way of telling is to try a write.There could be a lot of other reasons why the request/response can fail.That is why I normally recommend using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.With sniffer you can tell if the status in the response is 200 OK or an error response.  You can also look ant the xml in the response and check if it is valid.  See if this helps : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ecc7e80c-6b5e-40a3-9cb8-7c209eef3155/exception-handling-in-web-services?forum=asmxandxml